# Can't install slackpkg because the /etc/slackpkg/mirorrs file is missing

Tags: slackware

I get the errors

```
cat: can't open `/etc/slackware-version': No such file or directory
sed: can't read /etc/slackpkg/mirrors: No such file or directory
/mnt/usr/sbin/slackpkg: line 40: /etc/slackpkg/slackpkg.conf: No such file or directory
```

I need `slackpkg` to install other software, but how can I get `slackpkg` to work?

Comment: Slackpkg is installed by default. Did you remove it manually or something? How are you installing slackpkg?

Answer (score 1):

To install any package on Slackware without `slackpkg`, you have to:

1. Download package you want to install from https://packages.slackware.com manually.
2. As a root `installpkg <package>`.

There is also `upgradepkg` and `removepkg`. If you prefere menu driven stuff, you can use `pkgtool` which can install, remove etc packages. They all come with `pkgtools` package which should be installed by default.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how I would find the packages in question? Namely vim, slackpkg, and gcc.

Comment: Also, I have a user kbelcher, but there is no directory /home/kbelcher. What's up with that? Should I just create it manually and chmod it appropriately?